Wrong offset around Google Speech transcript
This is more of an open bug report for G engineers, since I could not find a better place to report this issue.
We've been using the chirp model in production to transcribe phone calls having two channels: caller and callee.
As we may see below, we received a report from a customer complaining about a weird display in the transcript due to the endOffset lasting longer than the next startOffset:
{
"alternatives": [
{
"transcript": " No, I'm not. Yeah.",
"words": [
{ "startOffset": "33.240s", "endOffset": "33.440s", "word": "No," },
{ "startOffset": "33.440s", "endOffset": "33.680s", "word": "I'm" },
{
"startOffset": "33.680s",
"endOffset": "53.320s",
"word": "not."
},
{
"startOffset": "53.320s",
"endOffset": "59.920s",
"word": "Yeah."
}
]
}
],
"channelTag": 2,
"resultEndOffset": "59.920s",
"languageCode": "en-US"
},

Basically, a single word appears as spanning through 20 seconds(!)
{"startOffset": "33.680s","endOffset": "53.320s","word": "not."},
Please, do let me know if you need any additional information from us helping you out to nail this one.
And thank you in advance for your kind attention.
